# Clustering in Bayesian Network Analysis (bnlearn)

Tags: cluster-analysis, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

everyone! I am new to this site, so please grant me patience if I'm doing this wrong or I incorrectly searched for this question and missed it in another forum. I'm currently a PhD student and trying to broaden my statistical toolkit. I'm trying to learn Bayesian networks and, at this moment, Bayesian Network Analysis specifically. I'm using the R package "bnlearn" and have no issues with the structure learning step. However, I have theoretical reasoning to believe my data may be clustered (by site the sample was taken) and I have no idea how to account for this in my analysis (or if I even need to account for it in BNA?) In the bnlearn manual, it talks about using the R package parallel, but I'm unclear if that is the actual answer to my question or if it's something different.

Has anyone done something similar or have any ideas how this is accomplished, if needed, in bnlearn?

Comment: Unfortunately, your questions is off topic for this forum because it is not about a programming / software problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic has more information and pointers to other forums that are more appropriate (and can help better).

Comment: I believe you need to adjust your data before running `bnlearn`. For example, you can either search the network structure within each cluster (this will reduce your sample size) or you can pre-adjust the clustering effect (e.g., fit linear model to remove clustering/group effect from data) if you want to use all data. @blmorgan